# Using view model organizes code, but does it have impact on performance?

Tags: asp.net, performance, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, datacontext

Part I
I am working on a web application that instead of using a viewmodel class to organize data and be used in View, uses a database table model. So for example in my view, model declaration looks like this: `@model aa.webobjects.object` - object is automatically generated by dbml. The question here is what is the benefit of using a viewmodel other than organizing data? I have another class, under dbml,  that for example does this:

```
public Product GetProductsByPrice
{
    get
    {
        return WebDataContext.Get().Products.Where(x => x.Price > 10);
    }
}
```

And basically this is used to organize data, and pull data from database as needed. The return statement brings us to question two.

Part II 
My application has a memory leak. The memory keeps growing and growing and after a while the server dies. As I read through some articles it seems like I should wrap my WebDataContext in `using` statement so that it'll recycle properly. My question here is: is not using Viemodel causing the memory leak, ir if I used viewmodels to organize data, and reorganize usage of WebDataContext so that it's wrapped in `using` statement would help?

I am not sure if this is explaining the problem correctly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is WebDataContext? Does it extend from DbContext, ObjectContext, or some other ORM?

Comment: I think it extends from System.Data.Linq.DataContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure you have to dispose your DataContexts instances (that's basically what using does). My suggestion is to add this in your Global.asax:

```
public void Request_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebDataContext.Get().Dispose();
}
```

and make WebDatacontext.Get() to return it from HttpContext.Current.Items.

In this way, your datacontext will be available for the whole request and it will be disposed when you don't need it anymore.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What is the benefit of using a View model?

1. You can use data annotations and model binding when you post back to the server.  This allows the creation of forms with validation checking much easier.
2. The objects coming out of your DB are being tracked for changes and carry some baggage with them. A view model (being a POCO) contains only the data you need with out all the other tracking tied to it. Passing a view model around is considered a better practice than passing entities around.